# paramiko no existing session exception

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

Using the python interactive shell and openssh running locally, I keep getting an "No existing session" exception using paramiko. My code is below.

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('localhost',username=name,password=pw)
```

Results in:

```
No handlers could be found for logger "paramiko.transport"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/paramiko-1.7.7.1-py2.6.egg/paramiko/client.py", line 332, in connect
    self._auth(username, password, pkey, key_filenames, allow_agent, look_for_keys)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/paramiko-1.7.7.1-py2.6.egg/paramiko/client.py", line 493, in _auth
    raise saved_exception
paramiko.SSHException: No existing session
```

I was able to connect previously, but had been trying to adjust this to allow for key based authorization. That failed, and since then I have not been able to connect locally. I have tried restarting openssh, and have connected to another server successfully. After searching through here, all I have found are mentions of authorization exceptions, which does not appear to be the case here.

Answer (score 56):

As you already have password you don't need to talk to agent or look for private keys stored on your machine. So try passing extra parameters `allow_agent`, `look_for_keys`:

```
ssh.connect('localhost',username=name,password=pw,allow_agent=False,look_for_keys=False)
```

Comment: This fixed my issue for connecting to a Cisco ASA 5515X with Paramiko 2.1.2 and Python 3.5.2.

Comment: I already have these set to false but this does not solve the problem for me. `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 190, in try_creds_and_get_stdout
    look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False, auth_timeout=30`

Comment: This also fixed my problem. paramiko was trying to use public key auth instead of the provided username and password. Thank you

Answer (score 14):

I had a spare public key with a key pass phrase in my ssh-add list. Once I removed it, I was able to execute my paramiko based script properly.

To list:

```
ssh-add -l
```

To delete all:

```
ssh-add -D
```

To re-add:

```
ssh-add /FULL/PATH/TO/id_rsa
```

Comment: ^ This works. Not sure why this isn't marked as the solution yet.

Comment: If anyone is using SSH keys embedded in your GPG key (ssh + gpg agent), make sure you don't have non-existing / no longer used SSH keys in the `~/.gnupg/sshcontrol` file.

I wasn't able to remove the SSH keys from the SSH agent with the `ssh-add -D` command. After I found out those keys were defined in the above mentioned `sshcontrol` file and removed them, everything started to work again - even for paramiko library...

Answer (score 4):

Just got the same error `ERROR:SSHException('No existing session',)` but since it was in a clean docker container, there was no ssh-agent.

After some hours of debugging, I found a different solution: it can happen when there is a timeout during key exchange! In my case, the ssh server is a router over GSM link, which is very slow.

You can enable debug on paramiko with:

```
logging.getLogger("paramiko").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

And if you see the exception between the `Connected` and the `Switch to new keys ...`, it means the timeout was during the key exchange. In this case, you have to set *timeout* to a bigger value! (documentation says *timeout* is only for TCP connect, but in fact, it is also for the whole negotiation before auth!)

Answer (score 3):

https://bugs.launchpad.net/paramiko/+bug/912123

Which OS are you using?
Maybe you can check your env variable:
SSH_AUTH_SOCK

for "connect", it will try to use ssh agent.
in agent.py

```
 self.conn = None
 self.keys = ()
 if ('SSH_AUTH_SOCK' in os.environ) and (sys.platform != 'win32'):
     conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
     try:
         conn.connect(os.environ['SSH_AUTH_SOCK'])
     except:
     # probably a dangling env var: the ssh agent is gone
         return
         self.conn = conn
 elif sys.platform == 'win32':
     import win_pageant
     if win_pageant.can_talk_to_agent():
         self.conn = win_pageant.PageantConnection()
 else:
     return
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case ,I have try use allow_agent=False,look_for_keys=False, but not work .
I ssh to a 2G device, so  timeout=10 is Ok, timeout=3 get" Unable to establish SSH connection: No existing session". Not timeout except.

So try timeout= a long time,if connect to a not establish ssh.

```
try:
     ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()               
        ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
                             ssh.connect(ip,22,username,passwd,timeout=10,allow_agent=True,look_for_keys=True)                     
                print ('%s\tOK\n'%(ip) )
        except socket.timeout:
                print ("%s time out"%(ip))
        except paramiko.AuthenticationException:
                print("Authentication failed, please verify your credentials: %s"%(ip))
        except paramiko.SSHException as sshException:
                print("Unable to establish SSH connection: %s" %(sshException))
        except paramiko.BadHostKeyException as badHostKeyException:
                print("Unable to verify server's host key: %s" %(badHostKeyException))
        finally:
                ssh.close()
```

Answer (score -7):

Replace 'localhost' by '127.0.0.1'.

Comment: I tried both localhost and 127.0.0.1 repeatedly with no success